# How can I store dates on a multi-dimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

How can I store dates on a multi-dimensional associative array?
I can't explain further my problem, but what if I have an array that contains different dates. For example:

```
<?php 
$dates = array("2015-06-01","2015-06-07","2015-07-08","2015-08-01", "2015-08-21","2015-08-26");
?>
```

I want to store the array above into multi dimensional associative array, according to their month, so therefore it would be like this..

```
<?php
array = array(
"June" => array("2015-06-01","2015-06-07"),
"July"=> array("2015-07-08"),
"August" => array("2015-08-01","2015-08-21","2015-08-26")
);

?>
```

But in my case, the dates are from the database compare to the example above that are defined dates, how can I group that following dates according to their month and store in an associative array named according to their month and the content is the second dimensional array that contains the date grouped?

Thanks!

My code above are just example: This is my solution but it's not working good! -_-

```
<?php 
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/empc/library/functions.php");
$previousmonth = "";
$a = getDistinctDates(); // Function that get dates, nevermind of this.
$data = array();
foreach ($a as $b){ 
    echo $b["date_modified"] . "<br>";
    $datemonth = date("F",strtotime($b["date_modified"]));
    echo $datemonth . "<br>";

    if ($datemonth != $previousmonth){
        array_push($data,
            array(
                $datemonth => $b["date_modified"]
            )
        );
    } else {
        array_push($data[$datemonth][],$b["date_modified"]);
    }

    echo $b["balance_after_approval"] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $previousmonth = $datemonth;
}
?>
```

Comment: return data sorted by month, loop check for month, trivial actually - tried *anything*????

Comment: The above code are just example, I just to need the concept and some of it's logic and I want to solve my own code on my own.

Comment: so what have you tried then?

Comment: make an array of month then use `foreach loop` then insert your `$dates`

Comment: dont even need to do that as you loop, use the month as the key

Comment: I dont have any $out variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your over thinking this, just use the month as the array key:

```
<?php 
$dates = array("2015-06-01","2015-06-07","2015-07-08","2015-08-01", "2015-08-21","2015-08-26");
$out=array();
foreach ($dates as $b){ 
    $datemonth = date("F",strtotime($b));
    $out[$datemonth][]=$b;
}
  print_r($out);

?>
```

demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Gh9s7